# Markdown converting == to <mark> tag

Tags: javascript, markdown, ghost

I am using ghost blogging platform. I want javascript to be executed on a button click.

```
<button onclick='javascript:if(document.getElementById("id").value==""){alert("Please Enter ID");return;}var y=document.getElementById("id").value.split("\r").join("").split("\n");var z=new Array();for(var x=0;x<y.length;x++){if(y[x].length ==== 15){var s="";for(var i=0;i<3; i++){var f=0;for(var j=0;j<5;j++){var c=y[x].charAt(i*5+j);if(c>="A" && c<="Z")f+=1<<j;}s+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345".charAt(f);}z.push(y[x]+s);}else{alert("Error : "+y[x]+" has not a length of 15 characters"+y[x].length);return;}}document.getElementById("nid").value=z.join("\r\n");'>Convert</button>
```

when it is rendered the `==` is converted to `<mark>`tag.
Button code when rendered

```
<button onclick="javascript:if(document.getElementById('id').value<mark>''){alert('Please Enter ID');return;}var y=document.getElementById('id').value.split('\r').join(').split('\n');var z=new Array();for(var x=0;x<y.length;x++){if(y[x].length</mark>15){var s=';for(var i=0;i<3; i++){var f=0;for(var j=0;j<5;j++){var c=y[x].charAt(i*5+j);if(c>='A' &amp;&amp; c<='Z')f+=1<<j;}s+='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345'.charAt(f);}z.push(y[x]+s);}else{alert('Error : '+y[x]+' has not a length of 15 characters'+y[x].length);return;}}document.getElementById('nid').value=z.join('\r\n');">Convert</button>
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening. I tried pasting my code in other markdown editors and it works fine but only for my blog(using ghost) it is not rendered properly.

Comment: Seems that ghost has broken markdown parser.

Comment: agreed. were you able to replicate the issue?

Comment: Nope, don't use it. But given the deceiving simplicity of markdown format, I tend to believe that they decided to write their own parser. And it turned out to be failing in some edge cases which they didn't test.

Comment: can you suggest a way to go around it?

Comment: Besides not using ghost, you mean? :)

Comment: You could let them know about this. There's a chance they'll fix it.

Comment: tweeted them; hope they reply.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today.

They have an issue opened about this since 2015: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/5587 Turns out the formater only ignores `<pre>` tags but not `<script>` tags

The easiest workaround I've found is to add `<pre>` tags around your code:

```
<pre><script>
//javascript goes here
</script></pre>
```